# Is this a good practice with functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, global-variables, local-variables

I am working on my very first python programming. I have no PC programming experience. I was having issues with using global variables inside my function. So I defined them again.

Here is the top of my program where I defined my global variables.

```
#Define Global Variables
segments = []
highscore = 0
currentscore = 0
delay = 0.2
level = 1
```

Here is one of the functions where I was using them. Everything worked but is this considered bad practice? Should I have passed them through as arguments? Just wondering what the best process for this is. I didn't want to post the full code because it's just over 200 lines and it is functioning fine.

```
def gameover():
    global highscore
    global currentscore
    global delay
    global level
    time.sleep(1)
    if currentscore >= highscore:
        highscore = currentscore
        sethighscore()
    currentscore = 0
    head.goto(0,0)
    head.direction = "stop"
    for index in range(len(segments)):
        x = 1000
        y = 1000
        segments[index].goto(x,y)
    segments.clear()
    delay = 0.2
    level = 1
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_global_variables.asp

Comment: I think you only need the global keyword when you want to change the global variable. In school, I was taught to capitalize both globals and constants.

Comment: this looks like better suited for [codereview.se]

Comment: No it's not. See [Global Variables are Bad](http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad) and [Global Variables Considered Harmful](http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesConsideredHarmful).

Comment: @buran when suggesting users post on CR it would be great if there was also a suggestion like "_Please read the relevant help center pages like '[What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)' and  '[How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)_". In the current form the code above would likely be closed as off-topic because it is missing context - [CR has an increased post size limit](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2325/120114) so users can provide sufficient context.

Answer (score 2):

Code best practice (not unique to python).

- Avoid mutability as possible
- Avoid global variables as possible (constants are OK)

for your case pass parameters, return value if needed

Comment: Thank you for the response. What do you mean by mutability? 

I am going to need to learn how to use parameters and return value. Back to youtube lol!

Comment: Mutability is changing variable value after initialisation.
This is very important for parallelism, and for unexpected result (if u are using global variable)